# converting a decode aes 128 python script to php fails with error:0606506D:digital envelope routines

Tags: python, php, php-openssl

I have a python script that works like expected and I tried to convert it to php without success.

The python code looks like this and is running as expected. I can get the results
Decrypted PICCData: c704366052e111900500005f07d56baa
PICCDataTag: c7
UID        : 04366052e11190
SDMReadCtr : 050000

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

# PICCData decryption
# PICCData = AES-128_DECRYPT(KSDMMetaRead; PICCDataTag[||UID] [||SDMReadCtr]||RandomPadding)

IV = 16 * b'\x00'
key = 16 * b'\x00' 

Enc_PICC_Data = b'38308EB36348ED39599ED6AFB1602F9F'

myaes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=IV)
PICCData = myaes.decrypt(unhexlify(Enc_PICC_Data))
PICCDataTag = hexlify(PICCData[0:1]).decode()
UID = hexlify(PICCData[1:8]).decode()
SDMReadCtr = hexlify(PICCData[8:11]).decode()

print('\nDecrypted PICCData: ' + hexlify(PICCData).decode())
print("PICCDataTag: " + PICCDataTag)
print("UID        : " + UID)
print("SDMReadCtr : " + SDMReadCtr)
```

The php code that should do the same actually looks like this:

```
<?php

$IV = str_repeat("\x00", 16);
$key = str_repeat("\x00", 16);

// Enc_PICC_Data = '\xEF\x96\x3F\xF7\x82\x86\x58\xA5\x99\xF3\x04\x15\x10\x67\x1E\x88'
$Enc_PICC_Data = hex2bin('EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88');

$ciphertext = openssl_decrypt($Enc_PICC_Data, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV);
if ($ciphertext === false) {
    echo "OpenSSL error: " . openssl_error_string();
} else {
    echo "The decryption was successful.";
    $PICCDataTag = bin2hex(substr($ciphertext, 0, 1));
$UID = bin2hex(substr($ciphertext, 1, 7));
$SDMReadCtr = bin2hex(substr($ciphertext, 8, 3));

echo "<br>Decrypted PICCData: " . bin2hex($ciphertext) . "<br>";
echo "PICCDataTag: " . $PICCDataTag . "<br>";
echo "UID        : " . $UID . "<br>";
echo "SDMReadCtr : " . $SDMReadCtr . "<br>";
}
?>
```

The decryption fails with the error:
`OpenSSL error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

Can someone help me correcting the php code?

PHP 8.1.15
open-ssl support enabled
open-ssl Version OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018

I tried the decrypt statement also as follows:
`openssl_decrypt($Enc_PICC_Data, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, 0, $IV);`
`openssl_decrypt($Enc_PICC_Data, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, option=0, $IV);`

And for the IV and key I also tried
`$IV = hex2bin("00000000000000000000000000000000");`
and
`$IV = base64_decode(str_repeat("\x00", 16),true);`

And for the Enc_PICC_Data I also tried
`$Enc_PICC_Data = hex2bin(base64_decode('EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88'),true);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the zero padding. I changed the openssl statement to OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING and it works now.

Thanks anyhow.